# Dash App not working when deployed on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to linux/aws in general and I am trying to deploy a dash webapp onto an ec2 instance. The webapp is written in python and uses an aws database. I created an EC2 instance, set the security group to allow all traffic, uses the default VPC and internet gateway. I successfully installed the all the app dependencies but anytime I run the app.py file. The public dns doesnt load the webpage. I have tried pinging the public IP and that works. I really have a limited knowledge base hear and have tried different options but cant seem to get it working. Please help :)

Public IP-https://ec2-3-8-100-74.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

[security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAw5z.png)
[webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S1qC.png)

Comment: did you try reaching your instance with its public IP? when its in default vpc you don't need internet gateway, internet gateway are required for private vpc ad private subnet

Comment: your ec2 instace is available from http://3.8.100.74/

Comment: Thankyou for having a look. I tried both the public IP and DNS address. The public IP returns that page on http and an error on https. I am also not sure why it returns the apache server home page

Comment: so the issue isnot with ec2 because it does allow you connections at the moment? are you sure your web app is running, check the ports you have configured for your web app

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I added an image that of the webapp running on the ec2 instance

Comment: https://ec2-3-8-100-74.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ the problem this link is not working because it has https, it should be http://ec2-3-8-100-74.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/, will take a look in your screenshot :)

Comment: ca you try edit app.py to enable flask to respond to requests from other than localhost. 
`app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`

Comment: @JatinMehrotra It leads to an error page

Comment: try gping through this once https://www.codementor.io/@jqn/deploy-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2-13hp1ilqy2 and https://www.twilio.com/blog/deploy-flask-python-app-aws, i went through both so this was something i thought you may see  when starting your application `flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080`

Answer (score 0):

I've been smacking my head on this for a couple days and finally got it. I know it's been a while but hopefully this helps someone else. Had a hard time finding answers elsewhere. Very similar to you, I had the ec2 instance set up, the security groups and vpc set up (those steps aren't too difficult and are well-documented). I had some successful pings, but was getting a "connection refused" error through the browser.

The "app.run_server()" parameters were the missing piece for me:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host= '0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

At that point calling the .py app gave me a 'permission denied,' which I was able to get around by running as sudo ("sudo python3 my_app.py") -- and by sudo pip install-ing necessary packages. (All through ssh, fwiw).

After finally running successfully I was given an IP from the dash app corresponding to my private IPv4 on EC2, and at that point could set my browser to the PUBLIC IPv4 and get to the app. Huzzah.

Playing around with it a little, it looks like as long as you have:

```
host= '0.0.0.0'
```

you'll run it online. Without that, it runs only locally (you'll see IP as 127.0.0.1). Then it's a matter of making sure whatever port you're using (:80, :443, :8050) is open according to firewalls and security groups. Dash for me defaults to :8050, and that port might be fine as long as it's allowed through security groups.

QUICK UPDATE:

I tried leaving it on port :8050, and also opened :8050 to all ipv4 in my security group. That let me run everything successfully without using "sudo python3".

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host= '0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

With "python3 my_app.py" in ssh

Comment: Hi! I have been following the same steps to deploy dash app on ec2 (8050 port). However, I could not access the DASH via https. I am only able to access it using http. Could you please provide details as to how I can host it on https?

Comment: @shubhamagarwal92 port 443 is for https, so check to make sure that you have permissions set for the security group for port 443.